# Which statistical test is appropriate for determining whether there is a significant difference in the exam scores of 2 groups(abnormal distrib)?

Tags: t-test

Male exam scores
58
54
61
64
60
60
45
44
53
54
32
56
43
69
69
72
66
45
63
49
48
53

Female exam scores
71
55
42
49
57
51
51
60
60
60
51
43
41
24
43
48
57
79
73
53
53
64
54
59
73
47

Comment: Discreteness (and test score bounds) aside, those data suggest they come from distributions that are not so terribly far from normality; QQ plots are pretty straight, for example. Being quite robust to mild departures from normal distributions, I would expect the t-test would perform quite well (both with respect to level and power) in such circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

The Mann–Whitney–Wilcoxon test is the simple nonparametric alternative to an independent samples *t*-test. Here's code and output in [r](/questions/tagged/r):

```
male=c(58,54,61,64,60,60,45,44,53,54,32,56,43,69,69,72,66,45,63,49,48,53)
female=c(71,55,42,49,57,51,51,60,60,60,51,43,41,24,43,48,57,79,73,53,53,64,54,59,73,47)
wilcox.test(c(male,female)~rep(0:1,c(22,26)))

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  c(male, female) by rep(0:1, c(22, 26)) 
W = 308.5, p-value = 0.6485
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Reversing the ordering of groups produces *W* = 263.5, but the same, insignificant *p* value. Following @Glen_b's [point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113072/which-statistical-test-is-appropriate-for-determining-whether-there-is-a-signifi/113074#comment216744_113072), a *t*-test gives a similar result (`t.test(c(male,female)~rep(0:1,c(22,26)))`):

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  c(male, female) by rep(0:1, c(22, 26)) 
t = 0.2615, df = 45.992, p-value = 0.7948
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -5.525451  7.175801 
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       55.36364        54.53846
```